# Can't change RMPointAnnotation image in Mapbox IOS Sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapbox, rmannotation

I am drawing a line in - (RMMapLayer *)mapView:(RMMapView *)mapView layerForAnnotation:(RMAnnotation *)annotation. But at the same time i also want to use a customise marker for annotaion. How can i do this. Any kind of help will be really appreciated. Below are my source code.

```
-(void) drawSipTrackerPath
{



    RMMapboxSource *tileSource = [[RMMapboxSource alloc] initWithMapID:@"id"];


    self.mapView = [[RMMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64, 375, 534) andTilesource:tileSource];

    self.mapView.delegate = self;

    self.mapView.clusteringEnabled = YES;

    [self.view addSubview:self.mapView];

    self.mapView.zoom = 3;

    self.mapView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;


    double latitude = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[self.trajectoryArray lastObject]valueForKey:@"lat"]] doubleValue];

    double longnitude = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[self.trajectoryArray lastObject]valueForKey:@"lon"]] doubleValue];




    for(NSInteger i=0; i < self.trajectoryArray.count; i++)
    {
        double latitude = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[self.trajectoryArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"lat"]] doubleValue];

        double longnitude = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[self.trajectoryArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"lon"]] doubleValue];

        CLLocation* location = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longnitude];

        [self.trajectoryArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:location];
    }


    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [self getLocationObject:latitude toLong:longnitude];

    RMAnnotation *annotation = [[RMAnnotation alloc] initWithMapView:self.mapView
                                                          coordinate:coordinate
                                                            andTitle:@"My Path"];
    annotation.userInfo = @"My path";

    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];


    RMPointAnnotation *annotationn = [[RMPointAnnotation alloc]
                                     initWithMapView:self.mapView
                                     coordinate:coordinate
                                     andTitle:@"Hello, world!"];


    annotationn.annotationIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow"];

    annotationn.userInfo = @"Hello World";

    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotationn];


    [annotationn setBoundingBoxFromLocations:self.trajectoryArray];


     [self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:coordinate animated:YES];

}

- (RMMapLayer *)mapView:(RMMapView *)mapView layerForAnnotation:(RMAnnotation *)annotation
{   
    if (annotation.isUserLocationAnnotation)
        return nil;

    RMShape *shape = [[RMShape alloc] initWithView:mapView];
    shape.lineColor = [UIColor redColor];
    shape.lineWidth = 5.0;
    for (CLLocation *point in self.trajectoryArray)
    {
        [shape addLineToCoordinate:point.coordinate];
    }


    return shape;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to branch in your `mapView:layerForAnnotation:` and inspect some property or properties of the `annotation` in order to determine whether it's your marker or your shape. Then you can proceed with either `RMMarker` or `RMShape` as appropriate.

I recommend the `annotation.userInfo` property for this sort of info.

Comment: If i branch this then shape never gets called and path isn't drawing. Can you please help me with this as i am having a hard time with this. Please check the source code screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/vbbswtwukisryva/Screen%20Shot%202015-08-21%20at%202.59.34%20PM.png?dl=0